# Hardness of the k-center problem with relaxed triangle inequality

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, np, approximation, clustering

Consider the $k$-center problem where we are given an undirected, complete graph $G=(V, E)$, with a distance $d(u, v) \geq 0$ for each pair $u, v \in V$. Furthermore, we assume that the triangle inequality holds: for each triple $u, v, w \in V$ it is the case that $d(u, w) \leq d(u, v)+d(v+w)$. The goal is to find $k$ clusters, grouping together the vertices that are most similar into clusters together. The goal is to choose a set $S \subseteq V$ of $k$ cluster centers such that we minimize the maximum distance of a vertex to its cluster center.

It is not difficult to show that there is no $\rho$-approximation algorithm for the $k$-center problem for $\rho < 2$ unless $\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{NP}$: Consider the dominating set problem, which is NP-complete.  In the dominating set problem, we are given a graph $G = (V, E)$ and an integer $k$, and we must decide if there exists a set $S ⊆ V$ of size $k$ such that each vertex is either in $S$, or adjacent to a vertex in $S$. Given the instance $G=(V, E)$ of the dominating set problem, we can then construct an instance $G'=(V, E')$ of the $k$-center problem by setting the distance between adjacent vertices in $G$ to 1 in $G'$, and the distances between nonadjacent vertices in $G$ to 2 in $G'$. Then, there is a dominating set of size $k$ if and only if the optimal distance ($OPT$) for $k$-cluster instance $G'$ is $1$. Thus, if we assume we have an approximation algorithm $A$ for the $k$-center problem with approximation factor $\rho < 2$, we can run it on $G'$. Then, if $OPT=1$, $A$ will return a solution with distance $<2$, i.e. 1. Else, if $OPT =2$, $A$ will return a solution with distance at least $2$. Thus, we can solve the dominating set decision problem, which implies that $\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{NP}$.

My question is then concerned with the $c$-relaxed $k$-center problem, where we do not have a metric but only the following approximate triangle inequality: For each triple $u, v, w \in V$, it is the case that $d(u, w)/c \leq d(u, v)+d(v, w)$. Is it possible to show that unless $\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{NP}$, there is no solution to the $c$-relaxed $k$-center problem with approximation factor $\rho < c+1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show hardness of approximation of any $\rho < 2c$.

Simply take the distance between non-adjacent vertices to be $2c$ and distance between the adjacent vertices to be $1$. Note that the graph should satisfy relaxed triangle-inequality, and it indeed does, given that $c \geq 1$.